# Detect videos with Youtube playback restriction

Tags: python, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am developing a web service using python and i want to filter out the videos which can not be played outside of the youtube page .

Like on this link [https://www.youtube.com/v/SC3pupLn-_8?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata]
you have to watch video on the youtube page is there is any way of filter which videos belong to the same category. So that i choose only those videos which can be played without any restriction.

```
import gdata.youtube.service
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
yt_service.developer_key = 'YOUR API DEVELOPER KEY'

count=0

def PrintEntryDetails(entry):

    if entry.media.category[0].text == "Movies" :
        global count
        count = count + 1
        if  entry.noembed != None:
            print 'Video embedding not enable: %s' % entry.noembed.text
        else :
            print "entry embedable"

        print 'Video title: %s' % entry.media.title.text
        print 'Video category: %s' % entry.media.category[0].text
        print 'Video published on: %s ' % entry.published.text
        print 'Video description: %s' % entry.media.description.text
        if entry.media.private != None :
            print entry.media.private.text
        else :
            print "Right not found"          
        if entry.media.keywords :
            print 'Video tags: %s' % entry.media.keywords.text
        print 'Video watch page: %s' % entry.media.player.url
        print 'Video flash player URL: %s' % entry.GetSwfUrl()
        print 'Video duration: %s' % entry.media.duration.seconds        
        # For video statistics
        if entry.statistics :       
            print 'Video view count: %s' % entry.statistics.view_count
        # For video rating
        if entry.rating  :    
            print 'Video rating: %s' % entry.rating.average
        # show alternate formats
        for alternate_format in entry.media.content:
            if 'isDefault' not in alternate_format.extension_attributes:
                print 'Alternate format: %s | url: %s ' % (alternate_format.type,
                                                     alternate_format.url)
        # show thumbnails
        for thumbnail in entry.media.thumbnail:
            print 'Thumbnail url: %s' % thumbnail.url        
        print "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"
    else :
        pass

def PrintVideoFeed(feed):
    counter = 0    
    for entry in feed.entry:        
        PrintEntryDetails(entry)
        counter = counter+1
        #print counter   


def SearchAndPrint():
    max = 20    
    yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()
    # OrderBy must be one of: published viewCount rating relevance 
    query.orderby = "relevance"
    query.racy = 'include'
    query.author = "tseries"
    query.max_results = 50
    index = 01
    for i in (range(max)):        
        query.start_index = index
        index = index + 50
        query.format = "5"
        feed = yt_service.YouTubeQuery(query)    
        PrintVideoFeed(feed)


SearchAndPrint()
print "**********************************************************"
print "Total Movies"
print count
```

Comment: Is there is any way of knowing that this video can not be played outside the youtube web site.Using python

Comment: The video claims it's embeddable, and provides an embeddable SWF URL. However, I can't test it, because it's not viewable in the US. Can you find a different example that's viewable world-wide, but cannot be embedded in an outside page or app? (PS, does https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC3pupLn-_8 have the same behavior as the full-screen, app-specific URL you posted? And have you tested the embeddable SWF URL, or any other means of embedding? What happens when you use it?)

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/v/MX6rC1krGp0?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata)   [link](https://www.youtube.com/v/_kmeFXjjGfk?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata)Please try this .The url i mentioned earlier was for flash player and i have alternate urls for that video but their resolution was very bad they are of 3gp format.Please help me out...

Comment: The second is again not available in the US. But the first one says "This video… is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on YouTube." That seems to be what you're looking for. I'll take a look, if you can provide an appropriate query that returns this…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're looking for the [app:control/yt:state](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt%3astate) tag. For example, if a video is restricted to playing on the YouTube site, but you're trying to access it through an embedded URL or through a non-browser, you'll get back something like this:

```
<app:control>
    <yt:state name="restricted" reasonCode="limitedSyndication">Syndication of this video was restricted.</yt:state>
</app:control>
```

You can see this in your `entry` object as:

```
entry.control.FindExtensions('state')[0].attributes
```

Which will be:

```
{'name': 'restricted', 'reasonCode': 'limitedSyndication'}
```

Of course you need to make this more robust—`control` may be None, it may have no `state` tags, etc. But you get the idea.

I don't think you can directly search on the presence or absence or particular value of `state`, but you can use the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial#Fields_Formatting_Rules) parameter to post-filter the results before retrieving them. The docs actually give the example of returning only "entries that do not restrict playback in any way, which is indicated by the presence of the `<yt:state>` element":

```
entry[not(app:control/yt:state)]
```

I've left off the `(title,media:group)` part because you want the default tags, not a limited set.

For some reason, the `fields` parameter doesn't always get sent. This may be because, as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters) say, "The fields parameter is currently used for experimental features only." But anyway, you can just retrieve everything and filter on `control` yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The general answer is to use the `format=5` parameter when performing your search: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#formatsp

That will filter out videos from the search results that have embedding disabled completely.

That being said, there are videos that have embedding enabled but only are playable in certain regions or when embedded on certain domains.

To handle the regional restrictions, you should set the `restriction=` parameter to something appropriate for your use case, as described at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#restrictionsp

There is no way to exclude videos from search results that have domain-level embed restrictions, though.

This blog post has more general information about embedded playback restrictions: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html